# Не срабатывает скрипт при нажатии кнопки

Tags: javascript

Необходимо при нажатии пробела нажимать кнопку (запускать скрипт).
Нашел готовое решение, но при переносе к себе оно по какой-то причине не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема.

```
window.onload = function() {

    document.getElementById('generate').onclick = Sch.click;

    document.getElementById('clear').onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML='';
    };

    document.body.onkeydown = function(e) {
        console.log();
        e = e || window.event;

        if(e.keyCode == 32) {
            Sch.click();

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А где функция Sch.click()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, догадался (включаем режим телепатии):

```
document.getElementById('generate').onclick = Sch.click.bind(Sch);
```

При назначении `= Sch.click;` эта функция будет вызываться в контексте DOM элемента, а не `Sch`.

```js
var Sch = {
  message: "test message",
  click: function() {
    console.log("Sch.click: " + this.message);
  }
};

window.onload = function() {

  document.getElementById('generate').onclick = Sch.click.bind(Sch);

  document.getElementById('clear').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = '';
  };

  document.body.onkeydown = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    console.log("onkeydown - " + e.keyCode);
    if (e.keyCode == 32) { 
      Sch.click();
      return false;
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<div id="generate">Generate</div>
<div id="clear">Clear</div>
<div id="results">Results</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.onkeydown = function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if(e.keyCode == 32) {
    console.log('Вы нажали пробел и Ваш скрипт запустился!');
    return false;
  }
}
```

P.S. Ну, разумеется, свой скрипт ставьте вместо строки *console.log*

Comment: P.S. Ну, разумеется, свой скрипт ставьте вместо строки"console.log....."